# web api is not returning json with all key value pairs for dictionary lookup

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have couple of classes for lookups in c# and an api method to return a Dictionary.
When I debug the method, I could see the Key value pair of dictionary with LookupDto and LookupListDto. 
    But when I fire it from the user interface, I could only see the  value of the last key pair of the dictionary missing out 
    everything else.

```
public class LookupDto
    {
        public LookupDto()
        {
        }

        public LookupDto(int id, string description)
        {
            this.Id = id;
            this.Description = description;
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class LookupListDto
    {
        public LookupListDto(int id, IReadOnlyCollection<LookupDto> items)
        {
            this.Id = id;
            this.Items = items;
        }

        public int Id { get; private set; }
        public IReadOnlyCollection<LookupDto> Items { get; private set; }
    }

    [Route("lookupdetails")]
    [HttpGet]
    public Dictionary<LookupDto, LookupListDto> GetLookups()
    {
        var abc = new Dictionary<LookupDto, LookupListDto>();

        //add few key values to dictionary
        return abc;
    }
```

Values sent out from API method

```
LookupCollection:{
    LookupKey:{Id:1, Description:"Test1"}
    LookupValue:{
            {
                Id:1221, Items:{
                        Id:001, Description: Child1
                        Id:002, Description: Child2
                        }
            }
        }
    LookupKey:{Id:2, Description:"Test2"}
    LookupValue:{
            {
                Id:1222, Items:{
                        Id:003, Description: Child3
                        Id:004, Description: Child4
                        }
            }
        }
    LookupKey:{Id:3, Description:"Test3"}
    LookupValue:{
            {
                Id:1223, Items:{
                        Id:005, Description: Child5
                        Id:006, Description: Child6
                        }
            }
        }
}
```

values received in the ui

```
LookupCollection:{  
    LookupValue:{
            {
                Id:1223, Items:{
                        Id:005, Description: Child5
                        Id:006, Description: Child6
                        }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Please give an example of the response from the server (not an image of the UI, but the json), and the final dictionary before you send it to the client.

Comment: Well, if `GetLookups()` does return all of the desired records and it's only in your UI that you don't see them, it's time to show the relevant UI code...